# Updating Attribute Editor

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to update all the tabs of the shaders (in the Attribute Editor) for every new shaders added. I chanced upon this Mel command - updateAE that I gather the information from [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/Commands/updateAE.html)

I tried doing a simple test, while I have a few surface shaders in scene, and running the following code:

```
ssList = cmds.ls(type = 'surfaceShader')

for each in ssList:
    mm.eval("updateAE \"string\" " + each)
```

But I got the following error instead,

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

or at times, this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error occurred during execution of MEL script
Line 1.33: Wrong number of arguments on call to updateAE.
```

Is this a viable solution else, are there any other similar scripting methods / functions that will enable to update the attribute editor?

Comment: The error you get says that `ssList` contains other lists, not strings. If it makes sense, you can to something like `mm.eval("updateAE \"string\" " + ' '.join(each))`

Comment: @Germano While trying out your method, I am getting the latter error `Wrong number of arguments on call to updateAE`

Comment: I know nothing about Mel, but from the doc you linked it seems like `updateAE` is expecting just *one* string argument and you are already passing a plain `"string"`. I'd look there for the solution.

Comment: @Germano I believe what you are saying is right. The mel seems to be looking for a single string rather than one that is read from the list, despite me adding `str(each)` or breaking up the list and inject it into the command... Unless I am doing it wrong

Comment: Have you tried: `for each in ssList: for i in each: mm.eval("updateAE %s" % i)`?

Comment: @Germano Thanks, it works. But I am still getting insignificant tab errors displayed in my editor...

Comment: why dont you register your own ae template?

Comment: @joojaa Hmm... I think I have tried it and it fails? I was working on custom shaders though. Probably it is something to do with it as the test example I have cited works. Apologize that my previous comment is misleading, sorry!!